# Is there a workaround for the hint bug?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-edittext

So I'm currently facing a bug on android, where if I set, for an EditText, a gravity to "center", an inputType and a hint, the hint is not displayed. I've tried multiple advices, like adding `singleLine="true", an ellipsize parameter, or a few others, with multiple combinations of these, but to no effect. I can only manage to get either my field not centered with a hint, or centered but without a hint.

The trade-off I currently use (no `inputType`):

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/view_email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingTop="7dp"
    android:paddingBottom="7dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:ellipsize="start"
    android:hint="@string/email_placeholder"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"/>
```

Apparently it's [a known bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7252), but I couldn't find any workaround that actually worked in my case. I just try to have an EditText for an input of type "email", with a centered hint.

Has anyone come with a workaround that actually works for this? I found out that it's quite a PITA for users to enter an email when the input type is not set to email.

Comment: Are you sure I am testing in nexus 7 and it is working for me

Comment: @IllegalArgument Well, I've tested on multiple devices, including a Nexus 10, and an LG Optimus Vu II, and it doesn't...

Comment: @JBL please post your entire xml or atleast edittext

Comment: Done, see edit. If I add the inputType property, the hint disappear

Comment: @JBL that is what I had suggested in my answer, if it helped please vote up for future reference to others :)

Comment: @Badrul I just added the maxLine properties, to no effect. (I already played a bit with the ellipsize property, either "start" or "end" don't work as well).

Comment: @JBL works fine on my device mate. Which device your are testing it on?

Comment: @Badrul As said, doesn't work on a Nexus 10, and an LG Optimus Vu II.

Comment: @JBL your entire xml is working in nexus 7 tablet kitkat latest 2012 model

Comment: @IllegalArgument Damn, could I have something completely different that disrupt the correct behavior? But where?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, give it a try

```
<EditText 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" 
    android:digits="0123456789.,"
    android:ellipsize="start" 
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:hint="@string/email_placeholder">
</EditText>
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you could use this as a workaround: https://github.com/malmstein/FloatingHints

Answer (score 0):

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/view_email"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="12dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:paddingTop="7dp"
android:paddingBottom="7dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:maxLines="1"
android:ellipsize="start"
 android:hint="@string/email_placeholder"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"/>
```

This works for me. just changed the height attribute

Comment: can you provide entire xml or the layout which this resides